# manipulando JSON JS

Tags: javascript, json

Quero saber por que isso funciona para alterar mas não serve para criar

```js
    var obj = {};
    
    obj.teste = {id:1}; //esse funciona para criar
    
    obj.teste.id = 2; //e assim eu altero
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
    
    
    var obj2 = {};
    obj2.teste2.id = 1; //isso não funciona, e pra mim faria sentido que o js criasse um obj com o id, mas ele da erro Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
    
    onsole.log(JSON.stringify(obj2));
```

Eu quero entender o ponto onde a minha intuição diz que o exemplo 2 deveria funcionar, mas não funciona.

Comment: Como assim não funciona pra criar? O que exatamente você está tentando fazer?

Comment: editei a publicação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então, cara. Quando você tenta acessar adicionar um valor para `obj.teste.id` acontece um erro pois o pai de id que é `obj.teste` é apenas uma variável e não um dicionário, estes são inicializados com {}. 
Os dicionário ou objetos, podem conter como chave um valor de texto. Exemplo:

```
obj.teste = {}    
obj.teste.id = 3;
obj.teste.indice1 = 4;
obj.teste.valorBool = true;
```

Porém, você só pode fazer algo deste tipo depois que a variável recebeu o valor de dicionário, que no código acima é mostrado como  `obj.teste = {}`. Portanto o `{}` é utilizado para inicializar o dicionário, por isso que todos os valores são sobrescritos quando você tenta usar `obj.teste = {id:1};`, **este serve apenas para inicializar**. Para alterar você pode usar o `obj.teste.id = 1;`

No caso do `obj2` acontece um erro pois `obj2` recebeu um dicionário, mas atributo `obj2.teste2` não, ele é apenas uma variável.

Comment: acho que entendi, tipo, tem que explicitar onde começa o dicionario

Comment: sim, basicamente isso.